# ReactJS / Firebase: Check collection map field if code exists and then update field within

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I have the following map within a firebase collection:

```
{
    "1234567890": {
        "Redeemed": false
    },
    "2234567890": {
        "Redeemed": false
    },
    "id": "4ced9690-4925-11ed-b8ce-cd7059f0665a"
}
```

What I am trying to do, is match the number to the user entering this via a textbox and then setting Redeemed to true if it matches ... it is basically for some promo codes.

How can I lookup the mapping number and then set Redeemed to true once submitted?

Is there a better way to set up this mapping/array?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you have read the document and stored the data in a variable

```
const data = {
    "1234567890": {
        "Redeemed": false
    },
    "2234567890": {
        "Redeemed": false
    },
}

// Take the user input as you want to 
const input = "2234567890";

// Checking if the key exist
try {
    const isRedeemed = data[input].Redeemed;
    console.log(isRedeemed)
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
}
```